# Django web application

Tags: django

I am using django and mysql for web application,web browser storing user visited templates in chache,when user logout from application user is accessing the templates

I used never cache to stop browser from caching,problem is it works fine when user logout but before logout also user can't access his visited templates by back button

Comment: You should add what you have try but not working as you expected.